# About WOJO PHP framework

Tags: php, frameworks, document

Currently, I am working on a system programmed under WOJO PHP framework. We have to update parts of it. Unfortunately, we cannot get the document about WOJO framework.

```
I just wonder whether some guy can help. 
Thank you so much in andvance.
```

Answer (score 0):

This one has been lying around for a while, so I don't know how useful my response will be.

I am currently trying to get to grips with something called Membership Manager Pro, which is from WoJoScripts.com

If this is at all related to the WoJo PHP framework above, the package comes in a zip file which contains some documentation.

A number of files contain information about the product and where it came from.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you mate. It looks like WoJo is not a open sourced framework. We turned to other frameworks.